# Unresolved reference: protoc - when using Gradle + Protocol Buffers

Tags: kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers

I have a gradle project which uses the Kotlin DSL

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.10"
}

group = "schema"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0"
    }
}
```

**schema.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
package schema;

message Message {
  string content = 1;
  string date_time = 2;
}
```

and project structure

```
schema
-src/main/proto/schema.proto
-build.gradle.kts
```

Whenever I run `gradle build` I get error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/x/schema/build.gradle.kts' line: 13

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

   Line 15:      protoc {
        ^ Unresolved reference: protoc

   Line 16:              artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0"
         ^ Unresolved reference: artifact

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```

The only thing I am doing different to various tutorials is using the Gradle Kotlin DSL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW you will get similar errors in Kotlin DSL (e.g. `Unresolved reference: id`) unless you import everything explicitly, e.g. `import com.google.protobuf.gradle.id`

Answer (score 25):

I think this is happening because you are referencing a single task within the protobuf gradle plugin. Try importing the whole bundle to make use of type-safe accessors as you desired.

```
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*
```

Answer (score 9):

For whatever reason this works

```
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protoc

protobuf {
    protobuf.protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0"
    }
}
```

It seems a little ugly having to specify `protobuf` twice mind

Answer (score 2):

This is works for me:

In project-level build.gradle.kts add this:

```
buildscript {
        dependencies {
           classpath("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.9.4")
        }
    }
```

In module-level build.gradle.kts add this:

```
plugins {
    ...        
            id("com.google.protobuf")
}
    
    android {
    ...
        protobuf {
            protoc {
                // find latest version number here:
                // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protoc
                artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.25.1"
            }
            generateProtoTasks {
                all().forEach { task ->
                    task.plugins{
                        create("java") {
                            option("lite")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    ...
        implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0")
        implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.25.1")
     }
```

Comment: Please [edit] & elaborate what this adds or changes over @Wadia SALEM‘s answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Kotlin, in your app-level kts gradle you need to import all from `protobuf` gradle `import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*` depending on [google/protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation)

```
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

plugins{
    ...
    id(""com.google.protobuf"")
}

android{
    ...
    protobuf {
        protoc {
           // find latest version number here:
           // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protoc
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:21.7"
        }
        generateProtoTasks {
            all().forEach { task ->
                task.plugins{
                    create("java") {
                        option("lite")
                    }
                    create("kotlin") {
                        option("lite")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to implement

```
implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0")
implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin-lite:3.18.0")
implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0")
```

The last task you need to do is to add the protobuf classpath to your project-level gradle kts

```
buildscript {

    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.19")
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me

Comment: The version `protoc:21.7` is like myth and source of compile error